# How to print a grid in python without quotes and commas

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a grid I want to print which is:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0']
```

I want it to be:

```
[0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0]
```

i.e. remove ONLY quotes `'` & comma `,`.

The code I tried:

```py
vertical=[]
horizontal=[]
size=5
def printgrid():
    for b in range(size):
        print(*vertical[b] ,sep='')
for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
        horizontal.append(0)
    vertical.append(horizontal)
    horizontal=[]
printgrid()
```

My code prints:

```
0000
0000
0000
0000
```

I tried using a few tutorials but it prints either without quotes only or without anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
vertical=[]
horizontal=[]
size=5
def printgrid():
    for b in range(size):
        print("[" + " ".join([str(i) for i in vertical[b]])+ "]")
for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
        horizontal.append(0)
    vertical.append(horizontal)
    horizontal=[]
printgrid()
```

`" ".join(x)` joins all the elements in `x` together with separator `" "`

`[str(i) for i in vertical[b]]` creates a new list where all the elements are the string equivalents of the original list

Comment: Thanks, it also works and it seems to be shorter than another way i got from someone else

Comment: @RoyalPhrog Perfect. If you are happy, please consider upvoting, and accepting as the correct answer.

Comment: got it i made it the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple might be a way to go.

how about using list expansion via:

```py
data = [
    ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0']
]

for row in data:
    print("[", end="")
    print(*row, end="")
    print("]")
```

giving you:

```
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
```

If you wanted to get a little more fancy, you could look at `join()` and `f-strings` and `list comprehensions`.

```py
print("\n".join(f"[{' '.join(row)}]" for row in data))
```

Which should give you the same result.

If in the end, you don't have a data list of list and just want to pass a size parameter to a method and hav that produce a reuslt, then you might do:

```py
def printgrid(size):
    cols = ['0'] * size
    rows = [f"[{' '.join(cols)}]"] * size
    print("\n".join(rows))

printgrid(4)
```

also generating a result of:

```
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: I tried it and i cant find a way to make it change depending on data i need

Comment: What is the format of your data? The first version I offered is based on a list of lists.

Comment: its a 4 lists in a list so like
[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

Comment: dont worry i already found an answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
vertical=[]
horizontal=[]
size=5
def printgrid():
    for b in range(size):
        print("[", end="")
        print(*vertical[b] ,sep=' ', end="")
        print("]")
for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
        horizontal.append(0)
    vertical.append(horizontal)
    horizontal=[]
printgrid()
```